# SQL: sum of a value but for distinct ids only - conditional sum?

Tags: sql, sum, conditional-statements

I have following structure:

Day with multiple events of typ1 and typ2, where typ1 and typ2 have foreign keys to their respective days. Typ2 also has duration.

Now I want to count all typ1 events, all typ2 events and sum of the typ2 duration.

Example Data:

Day:

```
ID = 1 | Date = yesterday | ...
```

Typ1:

```
ID = 1 | FK_DAY = 1 | ...

ID = 2 | FK_DAY = 1 | ...
```

Typ2:

```
ID = 1 | FK_DAY = 1 | duration = 10

ID = 2 | FK_DAY = 1 | duration = 20
```

I now want the result:

```
Day.ID = 1 | countTyp1 = 2 | countTyp2 = 2 | sumDurationTyp2 = 30
```

My problem is the sum, I need something like "sum for distinct typ2.ID"... Does anyone know a way to solve that?

I'm using something like the following, but that of course does not work the way I want:

```
SELECT day.id,
   count( DISTINCT typ1.id ),
   count( DISTINCT typ2.id ),
   sum( duration ) AS duration
FROM days
   LEFT JOIN typ
          ON day.id = typ1.id
   LEFT JOIN typ2
          ON day.id = typ2.id
GROUP BY day.id;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My general approach to this is to pre-aggregate each table, before joining.

Partly because you're not actually summing distinct values (if each of the two rows had `10`, the answer is still `20`).

But mostly because it's actually simpler that way.  The sub-queries do the aggregation, then the joins are all 1:1.

```
SELECT
  days.id,
  typ_agg.rows,
  type2_agg.rows,
  type2_agg.duration
FROM
  days
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT fk_day, COUNT(*) as rows FROM typ GROUP BY fk_day)  AS typ_agg
    ON days.id = typ_agg.fk_day
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT fk_day, COUNT(*) as rows, SUM(duration) as duration FROM typ2 GROUP BY fk_day)  AS typ2_agg
    ON days.id = typ2_agg.fk_day
```

Comment: . . I hope this is the accepted answer, because it is the right approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in my actual query that is more complex, that really makes it much more readable

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't done select statements within join statements yet.  This saved me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT day.id,
   count( DISTINCT typ1.id ),
   count( DISTINCT typ2.id ),
   (select sum( t2.duration )
    from typ2 t2
    where t2.id = day.id
   ) AS duration
FROM days
   LEFT JOIN typ
          ON day.id = typ1.id
   LEFT JOIN typ2
          ON day.id = typ2.id
GROUP BY day.id;
```

Comment: This introduces additional subqueries, and I believe the OP was looking for a single query solution.  Does your answer mean to imply it can't be written as a single query?

Comment: @Yuck - Where does it say `single query` or `no sub-queries`.  Why do you consider `sub-queries` not part of a `single query`?  *(If they're a `sub-` of something, they're a part of it, and `it` is a single query...)*  Not to mention that certain RDBMS are exceptional at expending sub-queries out.

Comment: FWIW that isn't my downvote.  And at least in SQL Server, this type of query has (often) severe performance penalties.  Not that it's wrong.  I was just asking the question - is there a way to do this without sub-selecting the tables involved?

Comment: I'm using SQLite and this answer is what I was looking for... if there is a faster way, I'm still intereseted in it though...